# Retrieving multiple values from the database using php unity3d

Tags: c#, php, database, unity-game-engine

I am making like RPG game where user can login and save and load the data. I can login and save. But, when I want to load the data, I am having a trouble to load that.

I will post the necessary code only (PHP code (Load.php)):

```
    <?PHP

    $Username = $_POST['Username'];
    $Location = $_POST['Location'];
    $Gold = $_POST['Gold'];
    $Level = $_POST['Level'];
    $Attack = $_POST['Attack'];
    $Defense = $_POST['Defense'];
    $MagicDefense = $_POST['MagicDefense'];
    $Evasion = $_POST['Evasion'];
    $Health = $_POST['Health'];
    $MaxHealth = $_POST['MaxHealth'];
    $Mana = $_POST['Mana'];
    $MaxMana = $_POST['MaxMana'];
    $Exp = $_POST['Exp'];
    $NextExp = $_POST['NextExp'];
    $AcceptedChiefQuest = $_POST['AcceptedChiefQuest'];
    $AddedChiefQuest = $_POST['AddedChiefQuest'];

    $con = mysql_connect("SERVER_NAME","DATABASE_NAME","PASSWORD") or ("Cannot connect!"  . mysql_error());

    if (!$con)
        die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());

    mysql_select_db("DATABASE_NAME" , $con) or die ("Could not load the database" . mysql_error());

    $check = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM Information WHERE `Username` = '".$Username."'");

    $numrows = mysql_num_rows($check);

    if ($numrows > 0)
    {
        while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($check))
        {
            $Username = $row['Username'];
            $Location = $row['Location'];
            $Gold = $row['Gold'];
            $Level = $row['Level'];
            $Attack = $row['Attack'];
            $Defense = $row['Defense'];
            $MagicDefense = $row['MagicDefense'];
            $Evasion = $row['Evasion'];
            $Health = $row['Health'];
            $MaxHealth = $row['MaxHealth'];
            $Mana = $row['Mana'];
            $MaxMana = $row['MaxMana'];
            $Exp = $row['Exp'];
            $NextExp = $row['NextExp'];
            $AcceptedChiefQuest = $row['AcceptedChiefQuest'];
            $AddedChiefQuest = $row['AddedChiefQuest'];

            echo $Username;
            echo $Location;
        }

        die();
    }

    else
    {
        die ("Data does not exist!");
    }


    ?>
```

And here where I access it by script in Unity (necessary code where the problem is):

```
    IEnumerator LoadCoroutine(WWW _www)
        {
            yield return _www;

            if (_www.error == null)
            {
                message = _www.text;

                if (_www.text == "Data does not exist!")
                {
                    message = "Data does not exist";

                    clickedLoadGame = false;
                }

                else if (_www.text == "Saved data does not match!")
                {
                    message = "Saved data does not match";

                    clickedLoadGame = false;
                }

                else
                {
                    if (_www.text == "Village")
                    {
                        GameManager.CurrentLocation = "Village";

                        GameManager.Loader = 1;
                    }

                    else if (_www.text == "Yein Plain")
                    {
                        GameManager.CurrentLocation = "Yein Plain";

                        GameManager.Loader = 4;
                    }

                    message = "Successfully Loaded.";

                    mainMenu = false;

                    yield return new WaitForSeconds(3);

                    Reset();

                    GameManager.LoadLevel("Loading Scene");
                }
            }

            else
            {
                message = "Error while trying to connect to the server.\nMessage: " + _www.error;

                clickedLoadGame = false;
            }
        }
```

The script only return single value which is **$Location** based on PHP code, and when I want to retrieve the **$Username** for example, the **_www.text** will be **VillageYunnan** which is I dont want, I want only the single value will be printed on **_www.text**, like **Village** or **Yunnan** and not **VillageYunnan** and that is only for 2 values, if I want to retrieve all of the **$** in PHP, it will be like **VillageYunnan15101010100** and so on, which will be very hard to maintain.

My question is I only want the **_www.text** only print like a single value and not combined together like I mention before.

Any help?

Really appreciate your answer.

Thank you

**EDITED: (Required Code)**

**GameManager.cs**

```
public static void WebsiteConnect(string link)
{
    wwwForm = new WWWForm();

    wwwForm.AddField("Username", LoggedInUsername);
    wwwForm.AddField("Gold", UserInformation.CurrentGold);
    wwwForm.AddField("Level", Status.level);
    wwwForm.AddField("Attack", Status.attack);
    wwwForm.AddField("Defense", Status.defense);
    wwwForm.AddField("MagicDefense", Status.magicDefense);
    wwwForm.AddField("Evasion", Status.evasion);
    wwwForm.AddField("Health", Status.hp);
    wwwForm.AddField("MaxHealth", Status.maxHp);
    wwwForm.AddField("Mana", Status.mp);
    wwwForm.AddField("MaxMana", Status.maxMp);
    wwwForm.AddField("Exp", Status.CurrentExperience);
    wwwForm.AddField("NextExp", Status.NextLevelExperience);
    wwwForm.AddField("AcceptedChiefQuest", QuestManager._acceptedChiefQuest);
    wwwForm.AddField("AddedChiefQuest", QuestManager._addedChiefQuest);
    }

    www = new WWW(link, wwwForm);
}
```

And i called it like this:

```
private void OnGUI()
{
if (GUILayout.Button("Continue", customStartButton.customStyles[0]))
            {
                clickedLoadGame = true;

                audio.PlayOneShot(audioSEClip);

                Load();
            }
}

private void Load()
    {
        GameManager.WebsiteConnect("WEBSITE_ADDRESS/Load.php");
        StartCoroutine(LoadCoroutine(GameManager.www));
    }

IEnumerator LoadCoroutine(WWW _www)
    {
        yield return _www;

        if (_www.error == null)
        {
            message = _www.text;

            var jsonObject = JSON.Parse(_www.text);

            //string jsonString = jsonObject.ToString();

            Debug.Log(jsonObject);

            if (_www.text == "Data does not exist!")
            {
                message = "Saved data does not match!";

                mainMenu = false;

                fadeAudio = false;

                yield return new WaitForSeconds(3);

                clickedLoadGame = false;

                Reset();
            }

            else
            {
                if (_www.text == "Village")
                {
                    message = "Successfully Loaded.";

                    GameManager.CurrentLocation = "Village";

                    GameManager.Loader = 1;

                    mainMenu = false;

                    fadeAudio = true;

                    yield return new WaitForSeconds(3);

                    Reset();

                    GameManager.LoadLevel("Loading Scene");
                }

                else if (_www.text == "Yein Plain")
                {
                    message = "Successfully Loaded.";

                    GameManager.CurrentLocation = "Yein Plain";

                    GameManager.Loader = 4;

                    mainMenu = false;

                    fadeAudio = true;

                    yield return new WaitForSeconds(3);

                    Reset();

                    GameManager.LoadLevel("Loading Scene");
                }

                else
                {
                    message = "Data does not exist!";

                    mainMenu = false;

                    fadeAudio = false;

                    yield return new WaitForSeconds(3);

                    clickedLoadGame = false;

                    Reset();
                }
            }
        }

        else
        {
            message = "Error while trying to connect to the server.\nMessage: " + _www.error;

            clickedLoadGame = false;
        }
    }
```

And here is the PHP code (Load.php):

```
<?PHP

$Username = $_POST['Username'];
$Location = $_POST['Location'];
$Gold = $_POST['Gold'];
$Level = $_POST['Level'];
$Attack = $_POST['Attack'];
$Defense = $_POST['Defense'];
$MagicDefense = $_POST['MagicDefense'];
$Evasion = $_POST['Evasion'];
$Health = $_POST['Health'];
$MaxHealth = $_POST['MaxHealth'];
$Mana = $_POST['Mana'];
$MaxMana = $_POST['MaxMana'];
$Exp = $_POST['Exp'];
$NextExp = $_POST['NextExp'];
$AcceptedChiefQuest = $_POST['AcceptedChiefQuest'];
$AddedChiefQuest = $_POST['AddedChiefQuest'];

$con = mysql_connect("WEBSITE_ADDRESS","DATABASE_NAME","PASSWORD") or ("Cannot connect!"  . mysql_error());

if (!$con)
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());

mysql_select_db("DATABASE_NAME" , $con) or die ("Could not load the database" . mysql_error());

$check = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM Information WHERE `Username` = '".$Username."'");

$numrows = mysql_num_rows($check);

if ($numrows > 0)
{
    while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($check))
    {
        if ($Username == $row['Username'])
        {
            $Username = $row['Username'];
            $Location = $row['Location'];
            $Gold = $row['Gold'];
            $Level = $row['Level'];
            $Attack = $row['Attack'];
            $Defense = $row['Defense'];
            $MagicDefense = $row['MagicDefense'];
            $Evasion = $row['Evasion'];
            $Health = $row['Health'];
            $MaxHealth = $row['MaxHealth'];
            $Mana = $row['Mana'];
            $MaxMana = $row['MaxMana'];
            $Exp = $row['Exp'];
            $NextExp = $row['NextExp'];
            $AcceptedChiefQuest = $row['AcceptedChiefQuest'];
            $AddedChiefQuest = $row['AddedChiefQuest'];

            json_encode($row);
        }

        else
        {
            die ("Saved data does not match!");
        }
    }

    die();
}

else
{
    die ("Data does not exist!");
}


?>
```

When I delete all the `$Username` and so on and replace it with `json_encode($row)` only and if the PHP code stays like above, the result still same, there is an error pointed at `string jsonString = jsonObject.ToString();` and the `var jsonObject = JSON.Parse(_www.text);` is null.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use some common format (like xml or json) to share structured data between different applications.

In PHP code replace:

```
$Username = $row['Username'];
$Location = $row['Location'];
$Gold = $row['Gold'];
$Level = $row['Level'];
$Attack = $row['Attack'];
$Defense = $row['Defense'];
$MagicDefense = $row['MagicDefense'];
$Evasion = $row['Evasion'];
$Health = $row['Health'];
$MaxHealth = $row['MaxHealth'];
$Mana = $row['Mana'];
$MaxMana = $row['MaxMana'];
$Exp = $row['Exp'];
$NextExp = $row['NextExp'];
$AcceptedChiefQuest = $row['AcceptedChiefQuest'];
$AddedChiefQuest = $row['AddedChiefQuest'];

echo $Username;
echo $Location;
```

with:

```
echo json_encode($row);
```

In C# code use some JSON library (like [SimpleJSON](http://wiki.unity3d.com/index.php/SimpleJSON)) to parse JSON string and retreive encoded data.

Comment: do you mean by replace the code is I should remove just the `echo $Username` and so on, or I should remove both the `$Username = $row['Username']` and `echo $Username` and replace it with `json_encode($row)`? Thanks

Comment: if you want to export whole object (i.e. all fields from selected table row) - then yes. If not, than you can create new associative array and json_encode it.

Comment: Hi @rtf_leg, I already tried the SimpleJSON, and replace the PHP code above with `json_encode($row)` and upload it to the server, and in C# I do it like this: `var jsonObject = JSON.Parse(_www.text);

            string jsonString = jsonObject.ToString();

            Debug.Log(jsonString);`

But when I run, it gives me an error of `NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object`. What could be wrong? Thank you

Comment: This means that you try to call instance method without instance. What line throws exception?

Comment: the error pointed at this code: `string jsonString = jsonObject.ToString();`

Comment: Ok, jsonObject is null and you try to call ToString() on it - NullReferenceException.

Comment: SimpleJSON as you suggested sir @rtf_leg. And in C#, I import it like `using SimpleJSON;` and yes sir, I just comment out the `string jsonString = jsonObject.ToString();` and Debug the `jsonObject`, the result was `null`.

Comment: Ok, it seems like JSON.Parse(_www.text) returns null. Can you show me contents of _www.text? SimpleJSON returns null for empty strings.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/72761/discussion-between-yunnan-and-rtf-leg).

Comment: @rtf_leg could you please edit the answer to include what you did in chat/comments to finish answering the question?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not 100% sure I get the question but I think this is the cause of your problems:

```
        echo $Username;
        echo $Location;
```

This would output `YunnanVillage` which is bad. Replace it with:

```
        echo '[' . $Username . ',' . $Location . ']';
```

This will output `[Yunnan, Village]`. You can now parse this string much more easily (it's a JSON format). Note that this is an extremely simple example, there are much better ways to output an array in PHP, for example:

```
json_encode(array('Username' => $Username, 'Location' => $Location));
```

I'm here due to c# tag but know PHP enough to see the error in your code. Hope this helps.

Comment: What i mean is, I want the output to be whether `Village` or `Yunnan` which from the PHP, i set echo `$Location` and `$Username`. But the problem is, when I set the echo like that, the result of `_www.text` is `VillageYunnan`. I apologize if my question did not clear enough. I will try your code and let you know @bokibeg. Thank you anyway for replying the question. And, if I already put `json_encode(array(blablabla));` in the PHP code, what can I retrieve the result in C#? is `_www.text` still do it?

Comment: You can parse the resulting _www.text via some JSON library in C# like rtf_leg suggested. Problem is that you aren't using the echo syntax correctly, check [this reference](http://php.net/manual/en/function.echo.php) if you're still confused about how to get the proper output.

Comment: Hi @bokibeg, I already tried the SimpleJSON, and replace the PHP code with `json_encode($row)` and upload it to the server, and in C# I do it like this: `var jsonObject = JSON.Parse(_www.text); string jsonString = jsonObject.ToString(); Debug.Log(jsonString);` But when I run, it gives me an error of `NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object`. What could be wrong? Thank you